# How to display multiple elements on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more than 1 link in my page. When I click the link, the input element shows up as shown in the demo below.
However, if I put 2 links it doesn't work.
I am pretty sure that problem is that I am repeating the id="barcode", which supposed to be used only once, but I couldn't find how I can resolve this.

https://jsfiddle.net/w3oz0txq/4/

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show() {
    document.getElementById("barcode").style.display = "block";
  }

</script>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show();">Please type barcode 1</a>

<div id="barcode" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
</div>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show();">Please type barcode 2</a>

<div id="barcode" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
</div>
```

Comment: Id should be unique. Can you change it to class = "barcode"?

Comment: Try different2 Ids or use class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery is tagged, I use a jQuery solution.

You are right, an id should only be used once. It needs to be unique.
So instead, use classes. Or search up/ down the DOM tree.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.show_barcode').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault; /* disable default click action */
    $(this).next('div').show();
    
    /*
    or if you want to hide the input after another click, then use next line 
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
    */
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="show_barcode">Please type barcode 1</a>

<div style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" />
</div>
<br>

<a href="#" class="show_barcode">Please type barcode 2</a>
<div style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" />
</div>
```

This function only works if the `div` is directly after the link.

So, if you want to move your elements around it might not work afterwards. You can change that by using `data-*` attributes. An example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.show_barcode').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault; /* disable default click action */
    var item = $(this).data('showitem');
    $('[data-input='+item+']').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="display: none" data-input="1">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" value="first input" />
</div>
<br>


<div style="display: none" data-input="2">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" value="second input" /> 
</div>

<a href="#" class="show_barcode" data-showitem="1">Please type barcode 1</a>
<a href="#" class="show_barcode" data-showitem="2">Please type barcode 2</a>
```

Comment: since it sounds like OP want to hide/show multiple elements this would be the best answer

Comment: If it were native javascript, I would have been perfect. since it is jquery it is great. Approved as answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign and pass different ids in show() as shown below

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function show(id) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
     }

 </script>
  <br>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show('barcode');">Please type barcode 1</a>

  <div id="barcode" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
  </div>
 <br>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show('barcode2');">Please type barcode 2</a>

   <div id="barcode2" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Rule **Id** should be unique for each element in HTML.

Use Jquery and play with Class attribute of element. Have changed the structure of body, Keeping anchor and input in a div together. When the anchor element is clicked, the input box enclosed within its div block is showed and rest are hidden.

Here is the JS fiddle for same : https://jsfiddle.net/w3oz0txq/30/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ele a").click(function(){
        $(".barcode").hide(); //hide all barcode input
        $(this).parent(".ele").children(".barcode").show(); // show the input box for link clicked
          });
      });

    </script>
<head>
<body>
<div class="ele">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >Please type barcode 1</a>

    <div class="barcode" style="display: none">
      <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" value="Bar 1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ele">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >Please type barcode 2</a>

    <div class="barcode" style="display: none">
      <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" value="Bar 2">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ele">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >Please type barcode 3</a>

    <div class="barcode" style="display: none">
      <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]" value="Bar 3">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use different IDs for each input and pass them in show() function to identify which input should be displayed.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  }

</script>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show('barcode1');">Please type barcode 1</a>

<div id="barcode1" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
</div>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show('barcode2');">Please type barcode 2</a>

<div id="barcode2" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach using class instead of id.

```js
var barcodes = document.getElementsByClassName("barcode");

for (let i = 0; i < (barcodes.length); i++) {
  barcodes[i].addEventListener("click", function(t) {
    var vis = this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display;
    if (this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display == "none") {
      this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = "none";
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<a class="barcode" href="javascript:void(0);">Please type barcode 1</a>

<div style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
</div>
<br>

<a class="barcode" href="javascript:void(0);">Please type barcode 2</a>

<div style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="barcode_values[]">
</div>
```